# From consumer end, Is there an option to create a topic with custom configurations?

Tags: spring-kafka

I'm writing a kafka consumer using 'org.springframework.kafka.annotation.KafkaListener' (@KafkaListener) annotation. This annotation is expecting the topic to be already at the time of subscribing and trying to create the topic if the topic is not present.

In my case, i don't want the consumer to create a topic with default configuration but it should create a topic with custom configurations (like the no of partitions, clean up policy etc). Is there any option for this in spring-kafka?

Answer (score 0):

See the documentation [configuring topics](https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/reference/html/#configuring-topics).

> If you define a `KafkaAdmin` bean in your application context, it can automatically add topics to the broker. To do so, you can add a NewTopic @Bean for each topic to the application context. The following example shows how to do so:

```java
@Bean
public KafkaAdmin admin() {
    Map<String, Object> configs = new HashMap<>();
    configs.put(AdminClientConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG,
            StringUtils.arrayToCommaDelimitedString(embeddedKafka().getBrokerAddresses()));
    return new KafkaAdmin(configs);
}

@Bean
public NewTopic topic1() {
    return new NewTopic("thing1", 10, (short) 2);
}

@Bean
public NewTopic topic2() {
    return new NewTopic("thing2", 10, (short) 2);
}
```

> By default, if the broker is not available, a message is logged, but the context continues to load. You can programmatically invoke the admin’s initialize() method to try again later. If you wish this condition to be considered fatal, set the admin’s `fatalIfBrokerNotAvailable` property to true. The context then fails to initialize.
>
> If the broker supports it (1.0.0 or higher), the admin increases the number of partitions if it is found that an existing topic has fewer partitions than the `NewTopic.numPartitions`.

If you are using Spring Boot, you don't need an admin bean because boot will automatically configure one for you.